# Crazy polynomial question

Tags: polynomials

Let $x_1,$ $x_2,$ $\dots,$ $x_{2016}$ be the roots of
$$x^{2016} + x^{2015} + \dots + x + 1 = 0.$$Find$$\frac{1}{(1 - x_1)^2} + \frac{1}{(1 - x_2)^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{(1 - x_{2016})^2}.$$

My solution: We can see that the polynomial is $\frac{1-x_1^{2017}}{1-x_1} = \frac{(1-x_1^{2017})^2}{(1-x_1)^2} = 0.$ Now we let $n = \frac{1}{(1-x_1)^2}$ and multiplying both sides by $(1-x_1^{2017})^2$ to get that $(1-x_1^{2017})^2 \cdot n = 0.$ Therefore, n = 0. And since we can do the same for the rest of the terms, the whole sum is 0.

However, this answer is not right and I do not know why it is not right. Can anybody help?

Comment: And the main problem is $n \ne 0$ (it can't be zero)

Comment: As $x_1\ne1$ it is evident that $1/(1-x_1)^2$ is **not** zero.

Comment: You effectively multiplied both sides by zero ($(1-x_1^{2017})^2 = 0$). So you cant infer anything from it. $n=5$ => $n\cdot0 = 5\cdot0 = 0$ doesn't mean that $n=0$.

Comment: You already know that $\ \left(1- x_1^{2017}\right)^2=0\ $ because $\ x_1\ $ is a root of the polynomial $\ x^{2016}+x^{2015}+\dots+x+1\ $, so it doesn't follow from $\ \left(1- x_1^{2017}\right)^2n=0\ $ that $\ n=0\ $.  In fact, since $x_1$ cannot be infinite, then $\ n\ $ cannot be $0$ either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint* as you mentioned $$1 + \dots +x^{2016} = \frac{x^{2017} - 1}{x-1} = 0 \iff x^{2017} = 1.$$

So you have all primitive roots of one modulo $2017$ (except $1$). It should be easy calculated then.

Comment: How would go about solving the problem with $x^{2017} = 1?$ Doesn't it make the denominators 0?

Comment: $x^{2017} = 1 \iff x = \exp(\dfrac{2\pi k}{2017})$, where $k = 1 \dots 2016$. We except case $x = 1$, to avoid zero denominator.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the expression directly using Vieta as follows:

Let $\zeta_k = \frac 1{1-x_k}$ for $k=1,\ldots, n=2016$.

So, we look for $\sum_{k=1}^{2016}\zeta_k^2$.

$x_k \neq 1$ is a root of $\frac{x^{2017}-1}{x-1}=0$ iff $y_k = 1-x_k \neq 0$ is a root of $\frac{(1-y)^{2017}-1}{(1-y)-1}=0 \Leftrightarrow 1-(1-y)^{2017}=0$ iff $\zeta_k\neq 0$ is a root of $1-\left(1-\frac 1z\right)^{2017}=0 \Leftrightarrow z^{2017} - \left(z-1\right)^{2017}= 0$

$$\Leftrightarrow z^{2016}-\underbrace{\frac{\binom{2017}{2}}{\binom{2017}{1}}}_{=\sum_{k=1}^{2016}\zeta_k}z^{2015} + \underbrace{\frac{\binom{2017}{3}}{\binom{2017}{1}}}_{=\sum_{1\leq j<k\leq 2016}\zeta_j\zeta_k}z^{2014} + \cdots =0$$

Now, we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2016}\zeta_k^2 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^{2016}\zeta_k\right)^2 - 2\left(\sum_{1\leq j<k\leq 2016}\zeta_j\zeta_k\right)$$ $$= \left(\frac{2016}2\right)^2 - \frac{2016\cdot 2015}{3}= \boxed{-338016}$$